# CSS Background Image on Top of other Content? (When Using Cover)

Tags: css

I have a CSS background image that I am using to fill the entire screen. I am using `cover` along with some IE fallbacks. When the background image loads it covers all of the content on the page, I cannot figure out why. Here is the code:

***CSS:***

```
#background-wrap{ 
background: url(/2012/images/august/moon-background.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
/* Cover for IE 7/8 */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='/2012/images/august/moon-background.jpg', sizingMethod='scale');
-ms-filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='/2012/images/august/moon-background.jpg', sizingMethod='scale');
/* End Cover for IE 7/8 */
background-size: cover;
background-color: transparent !important;
position:fixed;
top: 0;
left: 0;
width: 100%;
height:100%;
max-width:3000px;
max-height:1500px;
z-index:1;  
} 

.img-center{ 
    text-align: center;
    z-index:9999;
}
```

***HTML:***

```
<div class="img-center">
  <img src="/2012/images/august/neil-armstrong.png" class="feature-image" />
</div>
<!-- More Content --> 
<div id="background-wrap"></div>
```

I am not sure why this is not work.

*Note:* I will not assign the background-wrap CSS to the body or html tag for compatibility reasons with IE 8 and below. Here is why:

> Anyone trying to use the above IE filters and having problems with scrollbars or dead links or whatever else should try **NOT** using them on the `html` or `body` element. But instead a fixed position div with 100% width and height.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to wrap your background wrap around the content, not have it after it.

```
<div id="background-wrap">
<div class="img-center">
  <img src="/2012/images/august/neil-armstrong.png" class="feature-image" />
</div>
<!-- More Content --> 
</div>
```